# Do I need to replace the garage door opener or just the remotes to upgrade to rolling code technology?

Tags: doors, garage

I have an old Craftsman Garage door system from the mid 80s.  It still works great and for my cars, we have moved to the in car remote openers. We also have a wall remote code to access the garage door. One of our older cars still has the original opener which I believe is dip switch. Question- In order to move to a rolling code technology- Do I need to replace the whole system, or just the remote(s) and or the wall opener. The police were just here as someone remotely opened my garage door and then the dog scared them away.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it makes sense to spend money and effort retrofitting something on a 30 year old opener. How much longer do you think it will really last? New garage door openers can be had for around $150 and in addition to the "rolling code" remotes will include several other benefits like an electric eye safety sensor, auto-reversing contact sensor, vacation lockout controls, etc. If you want to spend more you can get other bells and whistles like quiet belt drives, wifi control, number keypads, battery backup...

Comment: Note: quiet belt drives are useless, if you have a loud metal door.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a HomeLink Conversion Kit. This will replace the wireless receiver of your old garage door opener. Or wire up like a button.

If the wireless receiver is built in to your opener then you will need to find a way to disable it, otherwise someone will still be able to send the dipswitch code and activate your opener.